# @JsonProperty does not change value while create JsonObject using Gson

Tags: java, android, jackson, gson

I have searched a lot but still i did not find any solution for @JsonProperty 
like below example

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

 public class MockMeter {

    @JsonProperty("serial")
    String mSerial;

    public MockMeter(String serial){
        mSerial = serial;
    }

}

MockMeter mockMeter = new MockMeter("KOTRDEMO"); 
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonObject = gson.toJson(mockData);
```

Here in string jsonObject i am getting **mSerial** instead **serial**

Can anybody help me what is the issue?

Comment: The `@JsonProperty` annotation is from [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), a JSON library. But you are using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), which is a different library. Gson does not understand the Jackson annotation. Use Jackson and not Gson so serialize your object to JSON.

Comment: Thank you so much let me try that way

Comment: It's working fine again thanks a lot